# How to show avatar only if it exists?

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

Is there any function in Wordpress that allows to hide the gravatar if id doesn't exists?

I have many authors that doesn't have a gravatar and all are displayed like this:

```
http://prntscr.com/98zsji
```

I would like to hide the default image.

I used the function `validate_gravatar($email);`, but it generated an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function validate_gravatar()
```

If I print `$user_email` it display correctly the user email.

Comment: FYI, for anyone wanting to merely hide the default avatar, there's an option for it in the settings: Settings › Discussion › Default Avatar.

Technically, a picture will still be displayed, it's just that it's a fully transparent one ([example](https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/c9e4e15ce475412a92a59573c9395161?s=32&d=blank&r=g)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use validate_gravatar which takes in the email address of the user and returns back true or false.

```
validate_gravatar($email); // returns true or false
```

**How to use it in your code:**

```
    $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_email');        

    if(validate_gravatar($user_email)) { 
        $author_avatar = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author_id ), '78', '', get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) );
    }

    // Now just echo where ever you want the image, it will show a default image if no gravatar is present.
    if(isset($author_avatar) && !empty($author_avatar)){
        echo '<img src="'.$author_avatar.'" />';
    }

   // In your Functions.php
   function validate_gravatar($email) {
    $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($email)));
    $uri = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash . '?d=404';
    $headers = @get_headers($uri);
    if (!preg_match("|200|", $headers[0])) {
        $has_valid_avatar = FALSE;
    } else {
        $has_valid_avatar = TRUE;
    }
    return $has_valid_avatar;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry about that, i though validate_gravatar is a core function, which it is not. so you will have to paste this function in functions.php

Comment: fantastic... now works. now with $author_avatar = 'ciao'; display ciao. How can hide the avatar ? if i insert $author_avatar = ''; remain the blank space

Comment: how i remove the blank space ?

Comment: well you should construct the link within the conditions. checkout the edited version

Comment: thank you for your help. It is Much appreciated. i mean : i want to hide the default image and i want to display only the user with avatar. The avatar now display correctly, but i want to hide the default image. but if i insert $author_avatar = '' remain a blank space. i want to eliminate this space thanks !

Comment: checkout the edit. You have to wrap your img with a condition to only show if gravatar is present

Answer (score 1):

Here is the filter that will do the trick:

```
function ns_filter_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args) 
{
    $headers = @get_headers( $args['url'] );
    if( ! preg_match("|200|", $headers[0] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    return $avatar; 
}
add_filter('get_avatar','ns_filter_avatar', 10, 6);
```

To work you have to add value `404` as third argument `$default` to `get_avatar()`. Example:

```
get_avatar( $user_email, 45, '404' )
```

Comment: This does work but unfortunately it *visibly* costly in terms of loading times.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the code below for a while and always work for me. The code is checked with PHPCS and WordPress Theme Standards and there is no errors or warnings.

The script profile-image.js is only enqueued on the respective page user-edit.php, that also applies for the media-upload and Thickbox scripts, this procedure will avoid any possible scripts conflict on your WordPress admin area.

```
/**
*
* Add custom user profile information
*
*/
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'ns_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'ns_show_extra_profile_fields' );
function ns_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
  <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
   <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="image">Profile Image</label></th>
        <td>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'image', $user->ID ) ); ?>" style="height:50px;">
            <input type="text" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'image', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><input type='button' class="button-primary" value="Upload Image" id="uploadimage"/><br />
            <span class="description">Please upload your image for your profile.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  <?php
 }

 /**
 * Enqueue a script in the WordPress admin user-edit.php.
 *
 * @param int $pagenow Hook suffix for the current admin page.
 */
 function ns_selectively_enqueue_admin_script( $hook ) {
   global $pagenow;
   if ($pagenow != 'user-edit.php') {
     return;
   }
   wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
   wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
   wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
   wp_register_script( 'profile-image', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/profile-image.js', array('jquery-core'), false, true );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'profile-image' );
  }
  add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ns_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' );

  /*
  * Save custom user profile data
  *
  */
  add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'ns_save_extra_profile_fields' );
  add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'ns_save_extra_profile_fields' );
  function ns_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
      return false;

    if(isset($_POST['image'])) {
     $imageprofile = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['image'] ) );
     update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $imageprofile );
    }
  }
```

profile-image.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(document).find("input[id^='uploadimage']").live('click', function(){
    //var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
    formfield = jQuery('#image').attr('name');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        jQuery('#image').val(imgurl);

        tb_remove();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```